# Code to be run automatically when the request is finished?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my own SQL based session class. I want to automatically commit the data in the session at the end of program execution (i.e. at the end of serving the page request). Do object destructors (finalizers) not get executed at the end of every request? Is there anyway of doing this instead of having to explicitly call a `Dispose()` method every time I am done with my session object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, finalizers are non-deterministic, which means you don't have any guarantee when it will be executed.  So, no, you can't use them for your scenario.

I see two ways to approach this:

1. Programmatically calling Dispose at some point towards the end of the page's [life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (or via the global.asax as mentioned by Michael G.).
2. Have your SQL based session class wire itself up to a page event (such as the **Unload** event) to do whatever actions it wants to clean itself up.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your question about suggestion #2, I will expound a bit.  This option would be to somehow allow your SQL based session class to gain a refernce to the web page instance.  One option (which I'll show below) would be to use the constructor of the SQL based session class to obtain a reference to the web page.  Then the SQL based session class can sign up for any event that it desires in order to know what is happening to the page.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
   using System.Web.UI;

   public class SqlBasedSession
   {
      public SqlBasedSession(Page webPage)
      {
         webPage.Unload += new EventHandler(webPage_Unload);
      }

      void webPage_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // the web page is being unloaded so this class can
         // cleanup it's resources now
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if this still isn't clear.

Comment: I am trying to get away from (1). I don't want to have to remember to do the commit myself at the end of every request. Also, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by (2).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is by using the global.asax. There is a handler for the end of a request, in C# the call inside global.asax.cs would look something list this:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //perform action - you have access to the HttpContext
}
```

You have to watch out for what is going through the handler though - depending on your configuration your assets (stylesheet, images, etc.) may also be hitting this request so you may have to devise a way to ensure only your pages have the actions taken on them.

Comment: I have tried this, and the public session object I create in global.asax does not seem to be available from any other object in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with IOC container provider for these kind of stuff. You can hook them up, to the end of a request and execute some code, especially good for some transactional stuff.

I have been using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), it has OnActivated() method, which I use to hook my transaction commits to on activation of session.